# Correctly type a Python subclass when the superclass is given as a variable

Tags: python, inheritance, typing

The following code snippet defines a function taking a class as input and returning a subclass with some overridden methods. The code works as intended, but the type hinting does not. The linter only recognizes the methods defined in the subclass, but I want to achieve the typed result as if the superclasses were given directly instead of through a variable (without repeating code). I have tried:

1. Typing the `scaler` variable in the function, but the linter still reads the superclass as `Any`.
2. Using generics, but this fails as the superclass must be a type and not a `TypeVar`.

I am using VS Code with Pylance as the language server, but I believe this problem is linter-agnostic.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing


def _scaler_factory(scaler):
    class DataFrameScaler(scaler):
        """Overrides methods to return dataframes."""

        def transform(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
            result = df if df.empty else super().transform(df)
            return pd.DataFrame(result, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

        def inverse_transform(self, df):
            result = super().inverse_transform(df)
            return pd.DataFrame(result, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

    return DataFrameScaler


MinMaxScaler = _scaler_factory(sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler)
RobustScaler = _scaler_factory(sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler)
StandardScaler = _scaler_factory(sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler)
```

Comment: "The code works as intended, but the type hinting does not." What type hinting? There's only one type hint here, `df: pd.DataFrame`. I do believe that is working as it should. Also, please make a [mre] that doesn't depend on pandas and sklearn.

Comment: If you're saying you want your IDE or mypy or whatever to understand that `_scaler_factory(Foo)` returns a subclass of `Foo` that additionally has `transform` and `inverse_transform` methods, I don't think you can facilitate that with type annotations. That's something the tool has to figure out for itself.